# Remove namespace inner node while serilization xml in c# web api

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am using webapi MVC template Using default XmlSerializer i get the following output

```
OUTPUT:
<ClassName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Child1>String</Child>
<Child2 xsi:nil=true/>
</ClassName> 

DTO class
[XmlRoot("ClassName")]
[DataContract]
public class ClassName
{
        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement("Child1")]
        public string Child1{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement("Child2",IsNullable =true)]
        public string Child2{ get; set; }
}
```

I managed to remove the root node namespace by overriding the default xmlformatter

```
//Code to remove root node namespace
  using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(streamWriter, settings))
                    {
                        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                        ns.Add("", "");
                        serializer.Serialize(xw, value, ns);

                }
```

But Now the namespace in the root node is removed but still the child node have the namespace

```
Current Output:
<ClassName>
    <Child1>String</Child>
    <Child2 xsi:nil=true p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</ClassName>
Expected output:
    <ClassName>
        <Child1>String</Child>
        <Child2 />
    </ClassName>
```

Comment: Did you check the possibility to _explicitly_ set the value of _Child2_ to `string.Empty` before serializing the object ?

Answer (score 5):

The namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is *required* to be added because you have specified [`XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Child2`.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The XML schema specification for structures allows an XML document to explicitly signal that an element's content is missing. Such an element contains the attribute xsi:nil set to true. For more information, see the World Wide Web Consortium (www.w3.org) specification, "XML Schema Part 1: Structures".
>
> If the IsNullable property is set to true, the xsi:nil attribute is generated for class members that have been set to null. For example if you set a field named MyStringArray to null, the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) generates the following XML code.
>
> ```
> <MyStringArray xsi:nil = "true" />
> ```
>
> If the IsNullable property is false, no XML element is generated for class members that have been set to null.

Where the `xsi` in `"xsi:nil"` is a shortcut for the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` as explained in [Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx).  As `xsi:nil` is a w3c standard attribute (defined [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil)), omitting the namespace would create nonstandard XML that would not be correctly understood by receiving systems.  Note that `XmlSerializer` only emits the `nil` attribute and associated namespace when required.  The XML output for

```
new ClassName() { Child1 = null, Child2 = string.Empty }
```

will not contain the attribute or namespace.

Incidentally, to clear up a possible confusion, in the XML

```
<Child2 xsi:nil=true p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

It is only the *`nil` attribute* that is in the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace, because only the attribute has the `p2:` prefix.  The `Child2` element itself is in the default namespace, so the presence of the namespace isn't changing the overall meaning of your XML.  In fact there's no reason not to leave the `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces on the root node.  Since they are *named* namespaces not default namespaces, elements and attributes will belong to them only if they have the appropriate prefix.

That being said, if for whatever reason you *must* use a custom `nil` attribute to represent a null text value, you will need to implement a custom property to serialize and deserialize it, for instance:

```
    [XmlRoot("ClassName")]
    [DataContract]
    public class ClassName
    {
        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement("Child1")]
        public string Child1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Child2 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Child2")]
        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public CustomXmlNilTextWrapper Child2Xml { get { return Child2; } set { Child2 = value; } }
    }

    public struct CustomXmlNilTextWrapper
    {
        bool forceNull;
        string value;

        public static implicit operator CustomXmlNilTextWrapper(string value)
        {
            return new CustomXmlNilTextWrapper(value);
        }

        public static implicit operator string(CustomXmlNilTextWrapper wrapper)
        {
            return wrapper.Value;
        }

        public CustomXmlNilTextWrapper(string value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.forceNull = value == null;
        }

        [XmlAttribute("nil")]
        public bool ForceNull { get { return forceNull; } set { forceNull = value; } }

        public bool ShouldSerializeForceNull() { return ForceNull == true; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get { return ForceNull ? null : value ?? string.Empty; } set { this.value = value; } }
    }
```

Serializing a default instance of this class will produce output like:

```
<ClassName>
    <Child2 nil="true" />
</ClassName>
```

This meets your requirement of not having a namespace - but it's not worth the bother in my opinion.

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFxX11) demonstrating how everything is working.